# IOS Developer account verify

Tags: iphone, ios, email, account

I am going to verify the email address,but it show me "**Your request could not be completed Invalid account for this Email Address**" after I signed in with my Apple ID and password.
The ID and password was right when I login the developer center,how can i save this problem?

Comment: Provide your apple id and password so that we can verify.. ;) Coool.. just for fun..contact apple. or try resetting the password with iforgot option.

Comment: I have contact Apple Developer Support and solve this problem,Thank you all the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging out and back in.
If that doesn't work, contact Apple Developer Support.

Comment: Yes. You'll need to contact developer support and have them sort it out for you.